# Struggling to rewrite a URL

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a page called pc_services.html and I want to rewrite the url so it displays as pc_and_network_specialists/services.html

I thought this code would do what I wanted:

```
RewriteRule ^pc_and_network_specialists/services.html&  pc_services.html
```

Though I get an access forbidden error and my URL displays as

```
*domain*/E:/xampp/htdocs/pc_and_network_specialists/services.html
```

Instead of

```
*domain*/pc_and_network_specialists/services.html
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect old to new
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} pc_services\.html
RewriteRule ^ /pc_and_network_specialists/services.html [R,L]

# Rewrite new to old
RewriteRule ^pc_and_network_specialists/services.html$ /pc_services.html [L]
```